# New button to create auto-populated quote record

Tags: trigger, sobject, create-records

I was wondering what the best approach would be to add a button on an opportunity page to generate a new quote record that has some data fields auto-populated with data from the parent opportunity.

Edit: Everything is working except for passing the contact through from the Opportunity to the quote.  I was hoping PrimaryContact__c.Id would work but it does not.

Edit2: The contact info is now passed through.  The quote gets created.  The last thing I need to do is add line items to the quote.  The issue seems to be that I can't set the QuoteLineItem's QuoteID because it is trying to grab the ID from a quote that was just created in the same script.  Is this possible to accomplish in the same script?  I have updated my code below.

Edit3: I have solved this and figured I would share my findings.  This quote list button passes Opportunity info into 2 newly created quotes.  I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this but this works for me.  The code is lengthy and I might move this to an APEX method when I have some free time.

Here is the code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/apex.js")} 

var connection = sforce.connection; 

//Create the new Quotes and set their OP IDs 
var newQuote = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
var newExpiredQuote = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
newQuote.OpportunityId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
newExpiredQuote.OpportunityId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 

//Some initital queries 
var contactQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT ID, Email, Phone From Contact Where AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' and Name ='{!Opportunity.PrimaryContact__c}'"); 
var opportunityQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Pricebook2Id From Opportunity Where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}' "); 

//Get the contact Name and Email for the Primary Contact for OP. If multiple records, use the last instance and this makes sure the contact belongs to the same account as the Op 
cont = contactQuery.getArray("records"); 

if(cont[0] != undefined){ 
idList = cont[cont.length - 1]; 
ContactID = idList.getArray("Id") 
ContactEmail = idList.getArray("Email") 
ContactPhone = idList.getArray("Phone") 
} 
else{ 
throw new Error('Please add a Primary Contact to this Opportunity'); 
} 





//Set the dates for on-time and expired quotes 
var date = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
var notesDate = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
notesDate.setYear(date.getFullYear() + 1); 
var month = notesDate.getMonth() + 1 

var expiredDate = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
expiredDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1); 

//Create the additional notes field 
var additionalNotes = "This agreement extends the CDRouter Maintenance and Support (MSA) license one additional year, through " + month + "/" + notesDate.getDate() + "/" + notesDate.getFullYear() + "."// This MSA will apply to the following system:"


//Add data to new on-time renewal quote 
newQuote.Name = "{!Opportunity.Name}"; 
newQuote.Pricebook2Id = opportunityQuery.records.getArray("Pricebook2Id"); 
newQuote.ExpirationDate = date; 
newQuote.ContactID = ContactID; 
newQuote.Email = ContactEmail; 
newQuote.Phone = ContactPhone; 
newQuote.Additional_Notes__c = additionalNotes; 
newQuote.BillingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 
newQuote.ShippingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 

//Add data to new expired renewal quote 
newExpiredQuote.Name = "{!Opportunity.Name}" + " Expired"; 
newExpiredQuote.Pricebook2Id = opportunityQuery.records.getArray("Pricebook2Id"); 
newExpiredQuote.ExpirationDate = expiredDate; 
newExpiredQuote.ContactID = ContactID; 
newExpiredQuote.Email = ContactEmail; 
newExpiredQuote.Phone = ContactPhone; 
newExpiredQuote.Additional_Notes__c = additionalNotes; 
newExpiredQuote.BillingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 
newExpiredQuote.ShippingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 

//Create the new Quotes and confirm success 
result = sforce.connection.create([newQuote]); 
result1 = sforce.connection.create([newExpiredQuote]); 




var quoteID = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From Quote where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}'"); 

var expiredqteID = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From Quote where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name} Expired'"); 


//Add the line items to the Quote 

//Get the line item details from the OP 
var items = sforce.connection.query("Select Amount, (Select PricebookEntry.Product2ID, ProductCode, UnitPrice, ListPrice, Quantity, OpportunityId, PricebookEntryId From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity where Opportunity.Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}'"); 

//Navigate to the correct data records 
i = items.records.OpportunityLineItems.records; 

if (i.length != undefined){ 

//Loop through each line item and create a new quote line item for non-expired quote 
for (j = 0; j < i.length; j++) { 

var line = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
line.Product2Id = i[j].PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
line.UnitPrice = i[j].UnitPrice; 
line.PricebookEntryId = i[j].PricebookEntryId; 
line.Quantity = i[j].Quantity; 
tempQID = quoteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
tempQID1 = String(tempQID); 
line.QuoteId = tempQID1.substr(0, tempQID1.length-3) 
addItem = sforce.connection.create([line]); 

} 

//Loop through each line item and create a new quote line item for expired quote 
for (p = 0; p < i.length; p++) { 

var exline = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
exline.Product2Id = i[p].PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
exline.UnitPrice = i[p].ListPrice; 
exline.PricebookEntryId = i[p].PricebookEntryId; 
exline.Quantity = i[p].Quantity; 
extempQID = expiredqteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
extempQID1 = String(extempQID); 
exline.QuoteId = extempQID1.substr(0, extempQID1.length-3); 
addItem2 = sforce.connection.create([exline]); 
} 
} 

else{ 
var line = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
line.Product2Id = i.PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
line.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice; 
line.PricebookEntryId = i.PricebookEntryId; 
line.Quantity = i.Quantity; 
tempQID = quoteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
tempQID1 = String(tempQID); 
line.QuoteId = tempQID1.substr(0, tempQID1.length-3) 
addItem = sforce.connection.create([line]); 

var exline = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
exline.Product2Id = i.PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
exline.UnitPrice = i.ListPrice; 
exline.PricebookEntryId = i.PricebookEntryId; 
exline.Quantity = i.Quantity; 
extempQID = expiredqteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
extempQID1 = String(extempQID); 
exline.QuoteId = extempQID1.substr(0, extempQID1.length-3); 
addItem2 = sforce.connection.create([exline]); 
} 
location = location
```

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson I have deleted my other post and updated this one

Comment: It's looking better. I already voted you up and can't offer much more help here. Good luck.

Comment: You don't have to edit Solved into your post titles. Accepting an answer indicates that quite clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/41.0/apex.js")} 

var connection = sforce.connection; 

//Create the new Quotes and set their OP IDs 
var newQuote = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
var newExpiredQuote = new sforce.SObject("Quote"); 
newQuote.OpportunityId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
newExpiredQuote.OpportunityId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 

//Some initital queries 
var contactQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT ID, Email, Phone From Contact Where AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' and Name ='{!Opportunity.PrimaryContact__c}'"); 
var opportunityQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Pricebook2Id From Opportunity Where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}' "); 

//Get the contact Name and Email for the Primary Contact for OP. If multiple records, use the last instance and this makes sure the contact belongs to the same account as the Op 
cont = contactQuery.getArray("records"); 

if(cont[0] != undefined){ 
idList = cont[cont.length - 1]; 
ContactID = idList.getArray("Id") 
ContactEmail = idList.getArray("Email") 
ContactPhone = idList.getArray("Phone") 
} 
else{ 
throw new Error('Please add a Primary Contact to this Opportunity'); 
} 





//Set the dates for on-time and expired quotes 
var date = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
var notesDate = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
notesDate.setYear(date.getFullYear() + 1); 
var month = notesDate.getMonth() + 1 

var expiredDate = new Date("{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"); 
expiredDate.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1); 

//Create the additional notes field 
var additionalNotes = "This agreement extends the CDRouter Maintenance and Support (MSA) license one additional year, through " + month + "/" + notesDate.getDate() + "/" + notesDate.getFullYear() + "."// This MSA will apply to the following system:"


//Add data to new on-time renewal quote 
newQuote.Name = "{!Opportunity.Name}"; 
newQuote.Pricebook2Id = opportunityQuery.records.getArray("Pricebook2Id"); 
newQuote.ExpirationDate = date; 
newQuote.ContactID = ContactID; 
newQuote.Email = ContactEmail; 
newQuote.Phone = ContactPhone; 
newQuote.Additional_Notes__c = additionalNotes; 
newQuote.BillingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 
newQuote.ShippingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 

//Add data to new expired renewal quote 
newExpiredQuote.Name = "{!Opportunity.Name}" + " Expired"; 
newExpiredQuote.Pricebook2Id = opportunityQuery.records.getArray("Pricebook2Id"); 
newExpiredQuote.ExpirationDate = expiredDate; 
newExpiredQuote.ContactID = ContactID; 
newExpiredQuote.Email = ContactEmail; 
newExpiredQuote.Phone = ContactPhone; 
newExpiredQuote.Additional_Notes__c = additionalNotes; 
newExpiredQuote.BillingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 
newExpiredQuote.ShippingName = "{!Opportunity.Account}"; 

//Create the new Quotes and confirm success 
result = sforce.connection.create([newQuote]); 
result1 = sforce.connection.create([newExpiredQuote]); 




var quoteID = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From Quote where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}'"); 

var expiredqteID = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From Quote where Name = '{!Opportunity.Name} Expired'"); 


//Add the line items to the Quote 

//Get the line item details from the OP 
var items = sforce.connection.query("Select Amount, (Select PricebookEntry.Product2ID, ProductCode, UnitPrice, ListPrice, Quantity, OpportunityId, PricebookEntryId From OpportunityLineItems) From Opportunity where Opportunity.Name = '{!Opportunity.Name}'"); 

//Navigate to the correct data records 
i = items.records.OpportunityLineItems.records; 

if (i.length != undefined){ 

//Loop through each line item and create a new quote line item for non-expired quote 
for (j = 0; j < i.length; j++) { 

var line = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
line.Product2Id = i[j].PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
line.UnitPrice = i[j].UnitPrice; 
line.PricebookEntryId = i[j].PricebookEntryId; 
line.Quantity = i[j].Quantity; 
tempQID = quoteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
tempQID1 = String(tempQID); 
line.QuoteId = tempQID1.substr(0, tempQID1.length-3) 
addItem = sforce.connection.create([line]); 

} 

//Loop through each line item and create a new quote line item for expired quote 
for (p = 0; p < i.length; p++) { 

var exline = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
exline.Product2Id = i[p].PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
exline.UnitPrice = i[p].ListPrice; 
exline.PricebookEntryId = i[p].PricebookEntryId; 
exline.Quantity = i[p].Quantity; 
extempQID = expiredqteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
extempQID1 = String(extempQID); 
exline.QuoteId = extempQID1.substr(0, extempQID1.length-3); 
addItem2 = sforce.connection.create([exline]); 
} 
} 

else{ 
var line = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
line.Product2Id = i.PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
line.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice; 
line.PricebookEntryId = i.PricebookEntryId; 
line.Quantity = i.Quantity; 
tempQID = quoteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
tempQID1 = String(tempQID); 
line.QuoteId = tempQID1.substr(0, tempQID1.length-3) 
addItem = sforce.connection.create([line]); 

var exline = new sforce.SObject("QuoteLineItem"); 
exline.Product2Id = i.PricebookEntry.Product2Id; 
exline.UnitPrice = i.ListPrice; 
exline.PricebookEntryId = i.PricebookEntryId; 
exline.Quantity = i.Quantity; 
extempQID = expiredqteID.records.getArray("Id"); 
extempQID1 = String(extempQID); 
exline.QuoteId = extempQID1.substr(0, extempQID1.length-3); 
addItem2 = sforce.connection.create([exline]); 
} 
location = location
```